# In a spring resource server using OAuth2, how can I provide a clientid to a keycloak server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I have the following scenario (a little bit narrowed down to make things easier):

- I have a keycloak server, with a realm, and two clients, one "base" client, one "spec" client. The base client has not authentication enabled, the spec client has authentication enabled.
  The base client has a home URL (http://localhost:4200), the spec client has none.
- I have a angular web application (http://localhost:4200), where the user logs on via keycloak. The angular web application has the clientid base.
- I have a spring applications which should be a resource server. It should have a clientid spec.

Now everything works as expected, when using the keycloak adapter in spring. As I have read, this is deprecated, so I decided to change it to OAuth 2.0 (with UMA).
When I visit the spec part in the browser, and angular asks the resource server for resources, the resource server checks that there is no rpt token and starts a communication to the keycloak, asking for a ticket.
The keycloak answers: "Client application [base] is not registered as a resource server."
This is of course true, the base client is not the resource server. But how can I provide the right client-id in spring?
In the old version, with the keycloak adapater, I had the property (applications.properties):
keycloak.resource = spec
With this, the keycloak adapter was able to communicate with the keycloak to receive a permission ticket for the client.
Is there something similar in OAuth 2.0? Or do I have to configure the keycloak server in another way, for this to work?
Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a resource server with JWT decoder(s) needs to contacts the authorization server (Keycloak in your case) only to fetch **public** tokens signing key (with Spring this is done once at application startup), and this does not require a client ID.

Client ID and secrets are required only when configuring a resource server for tokens introspection (introspection requests should be secured with a secret of some form).

**A resource server should not redirect unautorized requests to login**. This is the responsibility of clients and requires a session (requests to OAuth2 clients are secured with session cookies when requests to resource servers are secured with access tokens). Read the [OAuth2 essentials section](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) of my tutorials for more background.

With Keycloak, roles are, by default, part of access token claims:

- `realm_access.roles` for the "realm" roles
- `ressource_access.{client_id}.roles` for "client" roles (this requires a manual activation of client roles mapper)

Spring Security has nothing built-in to map Keycloak roles to "authorities" (what is closest to a "role" in Spring Security world): default converter uses only the `scope` claim as source to build Spring authorities.

If your need is to map client roles to spring authorities, [the official way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction) is to provide with a `Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken>` of your own when configuring the resource server in the security filter-chain. Something like that:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    Converter<Jwt, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter(@Value("oauth2-client-id") String clientId) {
        return jwt -> {
            final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
            final var clientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault(clientId, Map.of());
            final var clientRoles = (List<String>) clientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of());
            
            // Concat more claims if you need roles for other clients or realm ones
            return clientRoles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, ? extends Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
        return jwt -> new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt), jwt.getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME));
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter)
            throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(jwtResourceServer -> jwtResourceServer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(
                "/actuator/health/readiness",
                "/actuator/health/liveness",
                "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```yaml
oauth2-issuer: https://localhost:8443/realms/master
# Used in authorities converter
oauth2-client-id: change-me

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        issuer-uri: ${oauth2-issuer}
```

The configuration above also uses `preferred_username` (which Keycloak populates with user login) as Spring's `Authentication` name.

But you can do the same with no Java conf at all using the [`spring-addons-starter-oidc` I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
oauth2-issuer: https://localhost:8443/realms/master
oauth2-client-id: change-me

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        # you can add more entries if using several realms or instances
        - iss: ${oauth2-issuer}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          # you can add as many entries as you like for more clients or realm roles
          # you may also define a prefix (for instance "ROLE_") or case transformation (for instance `caze: UPPER`) for each claim
          - path: $.resource_access.${oauth2-client-id}.roles
        resourceserver:
          # entries listed here are accessible to anonymous
          permit-all:
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          - "/v3/api-docs/**"
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was following https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-grant-2.0.html#high-level-flow . There, the resource server sends "401 response with initial permission ticket, authz server location". Thats what I am trying to do (and that is what the keycloak adapter did, as far as I can see). In the keycloak docs, I read, that there is a "permission_endpoint" : "A UMA-compliant Permission Endpoint which resource servers can use to manage permission tickets. This endpoint provides operations create, read, update, and delete permission tickets in Keycloak".

Comment: ... This endpoint is the one, I am trying to connect to on the resource server.

Comment: This is the first time I read about this UMA thing. An important point to note is that it is not OAuth2 and as a consequence, there is nothing that expect from Spring Security OAuth2 about UMA. In the spec you link, it is even stated that how the resource server contacts the Authorization server is not in the UMA spec... If you ou want to stick to this UMA, I fear you'll have to implement all the extension by yourself (as well as the extension to the extension where the resource server fetches the "RPT" from authorization server)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in Spring OAuth 2.0 you can provide everything that is needed. Add the next dependency to your project

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

then you should set application properties

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=<client_id>
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=<client_secret>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using Spring Boot properties for OAuth2 clients with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My spring tells me that security.oauth2.client.client-secret is deprecated. Apart from that, I set security.oauth2.client.client-id but to no avail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).